# STm32L4R5VG firmware upgrade in run time

Tags: upgrade, stm32

In my application, I am using STm32L4R5VG as a host MCU. I want to upgrade the firmware of host MCU in run time over USB through the Android mobile app.

I have looked into USB DFU mode, but in that case, my device will enumerate as ST USB and also I need to enable the boot loader with boot pin.

In actuality, my device will connect with the Android mobile app using the CDC class device and enumerates as VCP. So I want to send the firmware file from Android mobile to host MCU over VCP and write into Bank2 of internal flash (as current code is in Bank1). Once the file transfer is done, the device will reboot on its own and check for the latest firmware and boots from Bank2.

I am stuck at how to write at bank2 securely during run time and perform self reset to boot from Bank2.

If anyone already worked on this or know about this then please guide me or point to the link where I can get details for this.

Comment: You can get an example for STM32L496 and STM32L476 
[here](https://github.com/akospasztor/stm32-bootloader)

Comment: But actually this example updates firmware from external memory card. But in my actual use case I am looking for dual bank feature but without using any ST  USB DFU mode to avoid enumeration.